# Copy directory not just the contents

Tags: directory, file-copy, recursive

I want to copy a directory into another directory.

For example, `cp -r dir1 dir2` copies the contents of dir1 into dir2. I want to copy dir1 itself into dir2 so that if I `ls dir2` it will output `dir1` and not whatever was inside of dir1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do as you did:

`cp -r dir1 dir2`

and you will have *dir1* (with its content as well) inside *dir2*. Try if you don't believe ;-).

The command that would copy content of *dir1* into *dir2* is:

`cp -r dir1/* dir2`

Comment: I tried it out exactly so and it worked. Then I went back to my original location and tried it, didn't work. Turns out bash's auto-complete suggested `cp -r System\ Volume\ Information test` only copies the contents, but if I manually type it out as `cp -r "System Volume Information" test` then it copies the directory itself and not just the contents.

Comment: I'll mark this answer as accepted because it is correct. The actual cause of the problem though was the spaces as described above.

Comment: @EricMajerus Your explanation of the cause does not make sense. I have added a new answer, that may explain things, it may be that the order of your tests, and not cleaning up after the first test cased the second to behave differently.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the manual for cp (also mv):

```
   cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
   cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
   cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
```

If you do `cp a b` then if b does not exist you get `cp -T a b`, but if b exists and is a directory you get `cp -t b a`, else error.

---

## Example

```
mkdir empty
cd empty
mkdir a
touch a/a-file
cp -r a b #this creates b a copy of a
cp -r a b #this time it makes a copy of a called a in b (b/a)
```

## Example 2

```
mkdir empty
cd empty
mkdir a
touch a/a-file
cp -r -T a b #this creates b, a copy of a
cp -r -T a b #updates b (no effect in this case)
```

## Example 3

```
mkdir empty
cd empty
mkdir a
touch a/a-file
mkdir b
cp -r -t b a #copy a into b
cp -r -t b a #updates a/b (no effect in this case)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the examples, resolved 15 min of painful debugging for me this morning!!

Answer (score 2):

Also, make sure that the first argument (the directory you want to copy) **doesn't end with a forward-slash character `/`**. Some versions of `cp` (for example on MacOS) treat it as `/*` and copy just the contents of the directory in such case, not the whole directory. And the forward-slash is usually added when you auto-complete the directory name using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

**Copy the whole directory** `dir1` into the directory `dir2`:

```
cp -r dir1 dir2
```

**Copy the contents of the directory** `dir1` into the directory `dir2`:

```
cp -r dir1/ dir2
```

It's equivalent to:

```
cp -r dir1/* dir2
```